# Is there a way to use java.net.http.HttpClient with Oauth2?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, httpclient, java-http-client

Hello I switched from `RestTemplate` to `HttpClient` from java 11. I want to switch from `OAuth2RestTemplate` to `HttpClient` from java 11 also.

I cannot find any materials about using `HttpClient` with OAuth2. Is it possible in easy way?

And is it good idea? Or should I use `WebClient` from spring?

Answer (score 8):

I just did post using `HttpClient` to grab OAuthToken and then I added token to headers of next requests.

```
String tokenRequest =
        "client_id="
            + lmGatewayCorrectClientId
            + "&client_secret="
            + lmGatewayCorrectClientSecret
            + "&grant_type="
            + lmGatewayCorrectGrantType;

    HttpClient oAuth2Client = HttpClient.newBuilder().build();
    HttpRequest oAuth2Request =
        HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .header(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
            .uri(URI.create(lmGatewayCorrectAccessTokenUri))
            .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(tokenRequest))
            .build();

    HttpResponse<String> oAuth2Response = null;

    try {
      oAuth2Response = oAuth2Client.send(oAuth2Request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```